# Joining the result of multiple select statements

Tags: mysql, join

I'd like to merge the results of the following three select statements horizontally. I tried using joins but no idea how to proceed since it involves COUNT and GROUP BY too.

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) as date,COUNT(*) as countd1 FROM b_users WHERE last_loggedin_at < DATE_ADD(created_at,INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
SELECT DATE(created_at) as date,COUNT(*) as countd2 FROM b_users WHERE last_loggedin_at < DATE_ADD(created_at,INTERVAL 2 DAY) GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
SELECT DATE(created_at) as date,COUNT(*) as countd3 FROM b_users WHERE last_loggedin_at < DATE_ADD(created_at,INTERVAL 3 DAY) GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

The individual results would be

```
date        countd1
2011-12-01   100
2011-12-02   120
2011-12-03   130

date        countd2
2011-12-01   200
2011-12-02   220
2011-12-03   230

date        countd3
2011-12-01   300
2011-12-02   320
2011-12-03   330
```

But I'd like to merge them so that I'll get the following result

```
date        countd1    countd2    countd3
2011-12-01   100        200        300
2011-12-02   120        220        320
2011-12-03   130        230        330
```

How do I do this?

Is it possible to do something like the query below

```
SELECT a, COUNT(b where condition), COUNT(c where condition) FROM table GROUP BY a
```

.

**Update**

biziclop provided a great work around

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) AS date,
SUM(last_loggedin_at < DATE_ADD( created_at,INTERVAL 1 DAY )) AS countd1,
SUM(last_loggedin_at < DATE_ADD( created_at,INTERVAL 2 DAY )) AS countd2,
SUM(last_loggedin_at < DATE_ADD( created_at,INTERVAL 3 DAY )) AS countd3
FROM b_users GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

Solved, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL the results of comparisons are 1 if true, 0 if false, so you could `SUM()` them:

```
SELECT
  DATE(created_at) AS date,
  SUM( last_loggedin_at < DATE_ADD( created_at,INTERVAL 1 DAY )) AS countd1,
  SUM( last_loggedin_at < DATE_ADD( created_at,INTERVAL 2 DAY )) AS countd2,
  SUM( last_loggedin_at < DATE_ADD( created_at,INTERVAL 3 DAY )) AS countd3,
FROM b_users
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```